# Convert WGS84 coordinate to Google Map coordinate system (EPSG::3785) with GeoTools and Java

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools, wgs84, epsg

Could you please point me out where can I make such a transformation:

Convert WGS84 (EPSG::4326) coordinate to Google Map coordinate system (EPSG::3785), and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the help of http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/api/jts.html I was able to do needed convertation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CRS tutorial at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/examples/crslab.html?

Comment: iant, yes, i`ve seen that. It is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Trust me it is relevant